# Is vectorizing backpropagation feasible?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation

Does it make sense to have the backpropagation of a neural network layer happen all at once if the learning rate is lowered? This would mean the new weights of that layer would be independent of each other, **but**, it would be extremely fast. Is this method feasible in any way for a neural network, or would it create a cost threshold which the network can't reach because of it's independent inaccuracy?

Comment: What do you mean by "all at once"? If I'm not mistaken, the way that backpropagation normally works is that all of the gradients are calculated (which is a very parallel process, but not 100% parallel) and then all of the gradients are applied at the same time. How does your idea differ from that?

Comment: Oh. The way I did it involved optimizing each weight one by one so that the other weights are related to them. I didn't know parallelization was the normal way to do it... No wonder it was so slow. Thank you so much! You just saved me from wasting 3 hours trying to find small optimizations.

Comment: I am still confused about how this works however. If the weights get optimized all at once, couldn't the previous influence of the weights on the layers' outputs make the new weights' outputs significantly different?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If the learning rate is too large, then that can be a big problem. I think that there are many possible ways to solve that problem. Using a smaller learning rate is one way. I don't know enough about machine learning to be able to name any other ways.